# Is Google Doc viewer can't work on localhost?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, google-document-viewer

I'm new at android. Im trying to open pdf file in Google doc viewer in android app through url from localhost. But google viewer show " No Preview Available " while url working fine on browser. Is google viewer can't work on localhost url or there is an error.?

[image: Error]

Comment: No, Google Doc viewer works with the sites that are available online. You need to find another solution for your localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Doc viewer works with the sites that are available online.
Instead Use this method:

Import Libraries:

`implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.kk121:File-Loader:1.2'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'`
and

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
}
```

In main.xml:

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdf_viewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

onCreate:

```
 Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new BaseMultiplePermissionsListener(){
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    super.onPermissionsChecked(report);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    super.onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions, token);
                }
            }).check();

    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdf_viewer);


    FileLoader.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .fromDirectory("PDFFiles",FileLoader.DIR_EXTERNAL_PUBLIC)
            .asFile(new FileRequestListener<File>() {
                @Override
                public void onLoad(FileLoadRequest request, FileResponse<File> response) {

                    File pdfFile = response.getBody();

                    pdfView.fromFile(pdfFile)
                            .password(null).defaultPage(0).enableSwipe(true).swipeHorizontal(false)
                            .enableDoubletap(true).onDraw(new OnDrawListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
                            //code if require
                        }
                    })
                            .onDrawAll(new OnDrawListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
                                    //code if require
                                }
                            })
                            .onPageError(new OnPageErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPageError(int page, Throwable t) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Occur ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .onPageChange(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
                                    //code if require
                                }
                            })
                            .onTap(new OnTapListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTap(MotionEvent e) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            })
                            .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight) {
                                    pdfView.fitToWidth();
                                }
                            })
                            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                            .invalidPageColor(Color.WHITE)
                            .load();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FileLoadRequest request, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> </application>
```

Comment: Does it work with MS Office docs, too? Can you, please, provide similar snippets for Angular?